# Finishing an intent activity while it is running

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an ACTION_CALL intent activity that I want to stop with code.

The problem exists on 2.3.3 When I end a call it goes to the call logs, instead of returning to the app directly which works on 4.1+.

I found that you can use finishActivity(requestCode) to finish an activity which doesn't work on my code.

Here is my code:

```
    startActivityForResult(callIntent, 2);


    // when I call finishActivity here it works fine and activity ends immediately
    // finishActivity(2);

    if (endCall) 
    {
        callEndTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) //End call after 10 seconds
        {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {

            }

            public void onFinish()
            {
                // end the call

                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                Class<?> c;
                try
                {
                    c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    Object telephonyService = m.invoke(tm);
                    c = Class.forName(telephonyService.getClass().getName());
                    m = c.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    m.invoke(telephonyService);

                    // Call ends here so I know the code is working
                    // When I call finishActivity(2) here the activity doesn't end and continues to go to the call logs
                    finishActivity(2);

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Any thoughts on why I can't end the activity?

Answer (score 0):

If your extending `Activity` in your class, just call `finish()` wherever you want the actvitiy to stop.

Comment: It extends ActionBarActivity. Calling finish() finishes my main activity not the call intent activity, so it doesn't solve the problem.